# I need to send an email with log4j

Tags: java, email, smtp, log4j, send

I have a problem. 
I try write an appender for my logger which must send an email from the  application. This is my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console, EMAIL 
....
log4j.appender.EMAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.EMAIL.SMTPProtocol=smtp 
log4j.appender.EMAIL.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.EMAIL.SMTPPort=25
log4j.appender.EMAIL.SMTPUsername=**
log4j.appender.EMAIL.From=**@**.pl
log4j.appender.EMAIL.SMTPPassword=**
log4j.appender.EMAIL.To=**@**.pl
log4j.appender.EMAIL.SMTPHost=smtp.**.pl
log4j.appender.EMAIL.Subject=Test Smtp
log4j.appender.EMAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EMAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.EMAIL.smtp.starttls.enable=false
log4j.appender.EMAIL.smtp.auth = true
log4j.appender.EMAIL.BufferSize=1
```

and I get this:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.**.pl", port 25, isSSL false
log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.**.pl, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.sendBuffer(SMTPAppender.java:330)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.append(SMTPAppender.java:215)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:322)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you able to connect to your smtp using telnet or ping ?

Comment: Yes, In windows console I can ping smtp.**.pl

Comment: Please try to connect using port...

Comment: in command line: telnet smtp.**.pl 25?

Comment: The Client cannot connect to port 25 on the server. Firewall not open? Network broken?

Comment: So what you need to do is check the exact details for the SMTP i.e IP:PORT. Once you are able to connect using command line than hopefully your code will work as well

Comment: @ Jabir and @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Thank you very much!